# Sending Multiple request to same function in .net application

Tags: .net, oracle, api, concurrency, .net-4.8

Hello my question is that i have a frontend application that is running in an entity , i want the best practice to solve the following sometimes 2 concurrent users do the same request the function they call in the backend go and select from the database the max no and add 1  to it the problem here i can't solve when 2 concurrent requests fires from frontend to backend because both fire the same request at sametime and select from database the same no so both updates with same value so one of them overwrites the other the difference between them is milliseconds but cant handle it

For knowledge the backend application is .net framework and database is oracle 19g

I dont know either if the 2 request are proceeding concurrent or parallel

Comment: The normal way to do this is to NOT write code where you have to read something from the database and then add 1 and then write it.

Comment: can you check if you can handle the issue with transactions ? otherwise can you share some code ?

Comment: @Ghassen transaction will hold the tablr for update not for selection what type of transaction should i add to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the below mentioned problem with the use of an **sequence**

> select from the database the max no and add 1.

You can create a sequence with start value as current max(column) like below

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name start with 300  NOMAXVALUE INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then use Sequence.nextval to get the next number like below

```
 seq_name.nextval
```

**Edit1**:-Since you have different entities you can do the below

```
 select max(order_no),seq_name.nextval
 from your_table;
```

In case you get the same  max(order_no) for same entities then check the seq_name.nextval value and increment the entity with max(order_no)+2 with a greater seq_name.nextval and then use max(order_no)+1 for the other user.Also try to drop and recreate the sequence everyday for better management

Comment: Look i cant make it with sequence because i have more than one entity so i want to choose the max no of this entity and add 1 but for sequence it will be same for  all table like invoice numbers

Comment: what are you selecting from the database when you say "select from the database the max no and add 1"

Comment: I have table for orders i have multiple entites i increment the order no for each entity i get the max then add 1 the order no isnt primary key i select the max order where entity = my entity  then increment  by 1 and add new record with thr incremented no so if 2 users from same entity tried to create orders at same time they will select same max order no

Comment: how many such entities are there ??

Comment: For no we have just operated 3 entites but thr problem happens for any entity when 2 users from same entity click on open order button at same time i cant prevent it

Comment: added Edit1 to solve your issue

Comment: In futurr we will have over 50 entites will work but this is not the issue the issue that the sequence how will it prevent the 2 users from reading the same max(order_no)

Comment: the sequence will  help us to know what is the actual placement of order if the max(order) is same.for example if ten users have same max(order) then the sequence will tell 1 to 10 the sequence in which to increment the order